# aspcore multiple policy with JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have two policy in place the ApiUser and CompanyBased. when I am using the companybased policy ([Authorize(Policy = "CompanyBased")]
) the application is failing to validate the JWT token. When I am using [Authorize] it works well, the token is validated...

Version: core 2.2

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ForbidResult[1]
Executing ForbidResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[13]
AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was forbidden.

```
        // api user claim policy
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
            options.AddPolicy("CompanyBased", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess);
                policy.AddRequirements(new CompanyBasedRequirement());
            });
        });
```

This is the CompanyBasedHandler

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CompanyBasedRequirement requirement)
{
    #region Validate Company id

    Guid? companyId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.GetCompanyId();
    string nameIdentifier = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    if (companyId is null)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"No company suppied for {nameIdentifier}");
        context.Fail();
    }
    else
    {
        if (!_clientRepository.IsClientValid(companyId.Value, nameIdentifier))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"{companyId} does not belong to {nameIdentifier}");
            context.Fail();
        }
        else
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }

    #endregion Validate Company id

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

1. How do I make sure that CompanyBased validates the the JWT token
2. Can I make the HandleRequirementAsync Async with await, I was stuck with return await Task.CompletedTask (which is not working)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol in the token!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you regisered your custom authorization handler correctly in your dependency injection container in the Startup class. It should be registered as a singleton:

`services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CompanyBasedHandler>();`

You can make the `HandleRequirementAsync` async/await by changing the the method signature to `async Task` and then not returning a completed Task at the end of the method, for example:

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CompanyBasedRequirement requirement)
{
    #region Validate Company id

    Guid? companyId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.GetCompanyId();
    string nameIdentifier = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    if (companyId is null)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"No company suppied for {nameIdentifier}");
        context.Fail();
    }
    else
    {
        if (!_clientRepository.IsClientValid(companyId.Value, nameIdentifier))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"{companyId} does not belong to {nameIdentifier}");
            context.Fail();
        }
        else
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }

    #endregion Validate Company id
}
```

> Note that you are not doing any asynchronous operations in the method, that means it will run synchronously thus there is not need to make this method async.

Comment: Even with the DI, i am getting into the same problem. Also according to you would it be wiser for me to create an Async on HandleRequirementAsync?

Comment: Do you have app.UseAuthentication(); registered in the Startup class?
No, returning a Task.CompletedTask is perfectly fine in your case.

Comment: Yes i have app.UseAuthentication

Comment: Can you show the class signature of the authZ requirement and handler?

Comment: It's an empty class: public class CompanyBasedRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement {  }